# Import component based on passed prop

Tags: reactjs, import, react-props, react-component

Is there a way to import a component based on what was passed from a parent component as a prop, something like

```
<ComponentA
   componentToLoad = '/path/to/componentB'
/>
```

and then in the `ComponentA` do

```
@import localComponent from {props.componentToLoad};
```

Comment: Is the goal to lazy load the code so you have a smaller bundle size? Or it's ok for the components to all be in the bundle but you only want to render one, which is chosen at runtime?

Comment: @NicholasTower I want to use  `ComponentA` as a generic which contains specific `localComponent` from `ComponentB` and `localComponent` is the same component but with different data for ex `ComponentD` etc

Comment: I don't think you understood my question, so let me try again. Assuming your project is like most, there will be a build step which goes through your files and bundles them together into a single file. That file is the one that loads when you launch the page. There are two broad ways to do what you want: 1) Have the bundle file contain both ComponentB and ComponentD, and then at runtime pick which one to use. 2) Have the bundle file contain **neither** of them, and then add some code to load an extra file at runtime

Comment: @NicholasTower I was thinking to go for #1 if possible. My goal is to minimize edits on components so in my case only `componentToLoad` need to be edited or created as another one. For example - table headers when a table as `ComponentA` stays intact - just loaded a data from API which was passed as a prop as well.

Comment: @NicholasTower I have got a workaround for my case  not perfect but works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find perfect solution but workaround mentioned below was good enough for me to achieve what I was looking for.

I have created common table headers index file which contains all locations for table headers:

tableHeaders.jsx

```
let tablelHeaders = {};

tableHeaders['propA'] = require('../tableA/tableAheaders.jsx').default;
tableHeaders['propB'] = require('../tableB/tableBheaders.jsx').default;
tableHeaders['propC'] = require('../tableB/tableCheaders.jsx').default;
...
tableHeaders['propX'] = require('../tableX/tableXheaders.jsx').default;

export default tableHeaders
```

and then in the view for the main component specify prop for that:

```
<MyTable tableHeaders="propA" />
```

and in the `MyTable` component access it as `require` instead of `import`

MyTable.jsx:

```
import tableHeaders from "tableHeaders.jsx;

....


const tableColumns = tablelHeaders[props.tableHeaders];
```

Hope it will helps someone else or somebody else will came up with better solution.